# Creating a separate sandbox environment

Tags: community, sandbox, environment

I'd like to create my own separate sandbox environment for development and test purposes but as far as I'm concerned the sandbox environment must be created in the production environment. The issue here is that I'm using the production environment of my client and I'd like to create a separate sandbox environment which is no created from my client production environment. Is that possible and how it can achieved?

Comment: and what did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: Why did you edit out your description of what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own developer account to have your environment with no restrictions https://developer.salesforce.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sandboxes create copies of your Salesforce org in separate environments. Use them for development, testing, and training, without compromising the data and applications in your production org.

Sandboxes are isolated from your production org, so operations that you perform in your sandboxes don’t affect your production org, and conversely. Sandboxes are nearly identical to your production org.

You need to create new sandboxes from Production environment as the sandbox metadata and data is copied from Production Org.

You can create development in Free Developer Org for your trial purpose, but the limitation here is you will not get the Production metadata and data in this org.

For trial purpose, you can create your own data model in Developer Org, which matches with the Production Org.

Comment: You can use a tool like the Salesforce Deployment tool to deploy the metadata from another environment to a Developer Org rather than manually creating it. You should never copy a clients data to any org outside their control as this will normally breach contract terms and often data protection laws.